# Проверка транзакции

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

есть два биткоин кошелька, подскажите, как через php  проверить транзакцию-был ли сделан перевод на на второй кошелек и подтвержден ли он?

Comment: через bitcoind?

Comment: а можно подробнее?

Comment: Самый безопасный способ - держать в себя запущенную полную ноду. Bitcoin Core клиент, bitcoind - это демон без UI. Вы конечно можете слать запросы на какой-то онлайн обозреватель блоков, типа blockchain.info, но это плохой способ.

Comment: у меня сайт на php и мне нужно как-то проверить была ли транзакция совершена на другой кошелек

Comment: Я это и понял с вопроса. И ответил

Comment: @Zergatul если там простой хостинг какой-то, то вряд ли может идти речь про демонов.

Comment: а если у меня на сайте 10 посетителей, и один хочет перевести другом? как мне проследить транзакцию по hash и кошельку второго клиента, чтобы узнать что второму клиенту пришли деньги?

Comment: @Aslero я ведь написал выше, используйте blockchain.info

Comment: да, но я не понял как проветить транзакцию по 2 кошелькам и хешу